# Find ancestor element and click on link using Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click on the 'a' tag using xpath, but unable to do so. As per my approach, there are 2 parts to it:
1) Find div element having text "See Reviews" - this is working to some extent

2) Find the ancestor a tag and click on it - this is not working. How do I get this right?

My code :

```
a = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'See Reviews')]")
```

This works without errors. But if change it to text()="See Reviews", I get NoSuchElementException

Further, for 2) I tried this but it throws NoSuchElementException

```
a.find_element_by_xpath(".//ancestor::a").click()
```

Below is the HTML structure:

```
<a class="cd ay at ce al cf cg b8 ch aq c7 c8 ci" href="/home/e747d172-2647-476a-a3d3-661a7b952919/feedback/restaurant?userUuid=undefined&amp;userExcludeExperiments=undefined"><div class="cj">See Reviews</div><svg width="16" height="14" viewBox="0 0 16 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform: rotate(0deg);"><path d="M15.65 7L10.775 13.75H8.15L12.275 8.125H0.5V5.875H12.275L8.15 0.25H10.775L15.65 7Z" fill="black"></path></svg></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preceding` in the same xpath to find the ancestor `a` tag.
Your code should be like:

```
a = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'See Reviews')]//preceding::a")
a.click()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.I'm still getting NoSuchElementError. The problem seems to be that its not matching div element. When I try browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'See Reviews')]"), it works but then when I try to find ancestor and click, it says ElementNotInteractable

Answer (score 0):

This XPaths should just work fine.

Shortest form :

```
//a[//div[.="See Reviews"]]
```

Alternatives:

```
//div[.="See Reviews"]/ancestor::a
//div[.="See Reviews"]/parent::a
```

More secure options :

```
//a[//div[normalize-space(.)="See Reviews"]]
//div[normalize-space(.)="See Reviews"]/ancestor::a
//div[normalize-space(.)="See Reviews"]/parent::a
```